# Eclipse rebuilds R every time

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Every time I start eclipse it opens my last opened Android project and starts recompiling R and others so for a few seconds I see lot's of **red error** markers on my scroll bar and I should wait until it finishes recompiling.

This behavior is new and I had not such problem before.

Answer (score 1):

***By default, the Eclipse workbench is configured to build projects automatically. However, for Android development you should disable this option, otherwise your entire project will be rebuilt whenever, for example, you save a change any file or restart the eclipse.***

Click `Project > Build Automatically` and ensure there is no checkmark beside the Build Automatically menu item.

Comment: But this was on before and I had no such problem!

Comment: You should had have the same problem. I've had this since forever.

Comment: This would be, when you added some lib projects